# Multiple UITapGesture on an UIImageView

Tags: swift

I have an image view, it looks like a 2d driving wheel, but instead of a game it’s a school project about rotating objects. by moving your finger on the image view, an uilabel should rotate according to the finger’s position.

So for the label I’ve created this:

```
let DeveloperLabel = “ i am a developer “
```

The label is created and positioned correctly, and I have an image view in the bottom of my screen, it’s set to be red, when the user taps the imageview I’ve attached a UITapGesture recognizer to it.

With this code:

```
 let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
```

So. for the `Selector`

```
func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{


Imageview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(.34906585);

    // Can’t get around it
}
```

The problem is, I tried to rotate the image once the image is tapped, but when the user taps the bottom of the imageview I want to call another function, same for the other corners

Sorry if it’s a weird question, this is the hard part of my homework, I also get 10 points if I do it correctly

Thanks

Sample image:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgwDK.jpg

Answer (score 2):

You would only need the single `UITapGestureRecognizer`, then when the method is called, figure out which quadrant for the image was tapped and then update the angle accordingly.

```
let location = tapGestureRecognizer.location(in: imageview)
let leftSide = location.x < imageView.frame.size.width / 2
let topSide = location.y < imageView.frame.size.height / 2
// based on the combination of the two, set the angle to the right value.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, so when the user moves their finger across the uiimage, will I be able to hit a function?

Comment: To track moving their finger, you would need to use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. The logic will be totally different than handling a tap depending on what you want the result to be.